# IN Luna eclipse and centos 6.0 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: eclipse, crash, java-8, eclipse-luna

I am using:

- Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) build id: 20150219-0600
- Java version "1.8.0_65", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode).

When I start Eclipse, it opens but as soon as I import my Maven project it imports up to 39% and suddenly crashes. I tried the following options:

- adding lines `--launcher.GTK_version` and `2` in `eclipse.ini`
- `org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` in `eclipse/configuration/config.ini`

But it didn't work. I have added the error log. Could you help me to find the reason for Eclipse crash please?

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc8725eeda0, pid=7822, tid=140498891028240

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x14da0]  _dl_x86_64_save_sse+0x30

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: Your crash is just a JVM crash, nothing specific to Eclipse. Have you tried looking up or submitting the bug to Oracle?